# Why do ActionLinks not show up in the design view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink, vwdexpress, designview

Is there any reason why ActionLinks aren't rendered by the VWD 2008 design view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionLinks for ASP.NET MVC are generated by a function call that returns a literal string. The design view is design for  ASP.NET Web Forms and does not evaluate any function calls.